# Filter out specific values and words from array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
debug: {ping: true, query: false, srv: false, querymismatch: false, ipinsrv: false, …}

eula_blocked: false
ip: "45.146.253.38"
online: true
players: {online: 0, max: 20}
port: 2018
version: "1.20.1"
```

I want to filter out `online: 0`and `max: 20`using JavaScript.
(The array is stored in a variable and comes from an API).

EDIT: I found a way to filter the values out, but it somehow only works if I manually input my data, and not if I use the data from the variable of the API response:

```
const data = {
    players:{online: 0,max: 20}
}

console.log("")
console.log("players online:", data.players.online)
console.log("players max:   ", data.players.max)
```

This works with the `const data` but not with the actual variable I want to work with, although it has the same structure. Why is that?

Comment: By filter out, you mean remove it from the result or only online and max would be the result? Could you show the expected output?

Comment: are use sure you resolved the data with `await` or `then()` ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 1):

The Array.filter is going to return the elements that follows an logic, for example [1,2,3].filter(num => num < 2) will return [1] so If you want a new array with the objects that have the properties online = 0 and max = 20 you should go for:

```
array.filter(item => {
  return item.players.online === 0 && item.players.max === 20;
}
```

Comment: Should be `item.players.online`

Comment: Yes, sorry. Didn't saw where these properties were writen so I answered thinking in a general object.

Comment: You can check the edit I made for my question if you want, maybe you have an idea on how to fix my trashy code....

Comment: I didn't understand yet what you want. Do you want an array with all the objects that have online = 0 and max = 20? Also, could you share more code, because since it works with manual input and doesn't work with the API return, it seems to be an problem with your fetch.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const responseData = [
  {
    debug: { ping: true, query: false, srv: false, querymismatch: false, ipinsrv: false },
    eula_blocked: false,
    ip: "45.146.253.38",
    online: true,
    players: { online: 0, max: 20 },
    port: 2018,
    version: "1.20.1",
  },
  // Add more objects here if there are multiple data points
  // {
  //   ...
  // },
];

// Extracting the 'online' and 'max' values
const playersInfo = responseData.map((data) => {
  const { online, max } = data.players;
  return { online, max };
});

console.log(playersInfo);
```

Map function iterates over each element in the `responseData` array and extracts the online and max values from the players object of each element. It then creates a new array called `playersInfo` containing objects with the extracted online and max values for each data point.